# How to manipulate individual group headers of gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

The following scenario:

I use a gridview to present grouped data.

I added a TextBlock to the headertemplate which 
should contain the number of items in this group. (For example)

*( Edit: In my scenario i show always 6 items and want to show the  overflow in the TextBlock children of my HeaderTemplate )*

How can i access the individual group headers from code to manipulate this TextBlock?

Here is an example of the result:

[image: Example Output]

And here a simplified example of my GroupHeaderTemplate:

```
<GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock x:name="overflow"/>
   </DataTemplate>
</GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
```

So i want to access and manipulate the "overflow" item individually for each generated group!

Comment: Hi Konstatin,
What do you mean by the "access and manipulate overflow item"?
As I understand "overflow" is a textblock. So do you wanna do something when you click the textblock?

Comment: @Haritha Hi! Even simpler, in my case i just want to change the text of each. whats necessary in general is getting a reference to the "overflow" textblock of each header.

Comment: HI! Have you tried to bind the "Text" property of the text box to display what you want?

Comment: Yes i did but unfortunaly its not that simple. Why that is should be explained with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get my hands on the desired Element by using the VisualTreeHelperExtensions

**First of all you have to install XamlToolkit via Nuget**

Afterwards add a using directive for the Extensions:

```
using WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.Extensions;
```

Now you can use several more methods on your ui elements , one of them is getDescendantsByType()
which i use to get all textblock elements hold by my gridview. I added a tag to my overflow textblocks which i check for when iterating through the gridviews descendants, see for yourself:

```
    private void ItemsGridView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TextBlock element in this.myGridView.GetDescendantsOfType<TextBlock>())
        {
            if(element.Tag != null && element.Tag.Equals("itemCountBlock")){
                element.Text = "Finally solved!";
            }
        }
    }
```

This should work out for any ui element and any property one would wanna change.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you really want.

**First edit the GroupStyle HeaderTemplate**

```
<GridView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle HidesIfEmpty="True">
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Width="500" Margin="5,0,0,5">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <Run FontFamily="Segoe Ui Symbol" Text="" />
                    </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Children.Count, FallbackValue=0}" />
                        <Run Text="Items" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        <GroupStyle.Panel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GroupStyle.Panel>
    </GroupStyle>
</GridView.GroupStyle>
```

> please note I am using a `VaraibleSizedWrapGrid`

**Next, handle the GridView's Loaded Event**

```
class SubtractConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object v, Type t, object p, string l)
    { return System.Convert.ToDouble(v) - Amount; }
    public object ConvertBack(object v, Type t, object p, string l)
    { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

private void GridView_OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as GridView;
    var converter = new SubtractConverter { Amount = 5 * 2 /* padding x2 */ };
    foreach (GroupItem group in (grid.ItemsPanelRoot as Panel).Children)
    {
        var result = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(group, 0);
        while (!(result is Grid))
            result = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(result, 0);
        var items = (result as Panel).Children.OfType<ItemsControl>()
            .First().ItemsPanelRoot;
        var binding = new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("ActualWidth"),
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Converter = converter,
            Source = items,
        };
        var header = (result as Panel).Children.OfType<ContentControl>()
            .First().ContentTemplateRoot as FrameworkElement;
        header.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, binding);
    }
}
```

And, presto! Now your header is perfectly sized to the width of the items in the group.

Things to remember (as the designer):

1. Your grouped items might be as narrow as a single column. Solve this with `TextTrimming` in the Header `TextBox`es.
2. Your grouped items might be wider than the monitor and `# items` might be off-screen. Solve this with a MinWidth on the containing `grid`.

Best of luck!

Comment: Sometimes the .Children collection is still null when you get in the _Loaded event because the UI is still rendering all items. Any tips on how to tackle this?

Comment: My guess is you aren't structuring your gridview the same as the sample.

Comment: Nope... not the case! When there is less data, it works. But when the items need to do async stull like getting images and there are a lot of items in each group - the collection is still empty when you already hit the loaded event of the grid! Placing it in OnLayoutUpdated works always,but than you do this to often :(